# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API: Why does it take so long to get a completion?

Tags: flutter, dart, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm trying to use GPT 3.5 in my Flutter app. I got answers but it takes 30-60 seconds to get a response. The code is the following:

```
 Future<String> getResponse(String message) async {
    OpenAI.apiKey = openApiKey;
    try {
      final chatCompletion = await OpenAI.instance.chat.create(
        model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        messages: [
          OpenAIChatCompletionChoiceMessageModel(
            content: message,
            role: OpenAIChatMessageRole.user,
          ),
        ],
      );
      print(chatCompletion);
      return chatCompletion.choices.first.message.content;
    } catch (e) {
      return "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
    }
  }
```

Right now I have a personal account, and I don’t have a paid subscription at the OpenAI site. Is something wrong with my code, or should I select a paid plan and will this solve the issue and will the response faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably due to the OpenAI server being overloaded.

As explained on the official [OpenAI forum by @rob.wheatley](https://community.openai.com/t/openai-why-are-the-api-calls-so-slow-when-will-it-be-fixed/148339/9):

> The last few days have been really quite bad. Even with streaming, a
> response could take a long time to start. But last night, as I was
> testing my new streaming interface, I noticed some odd, but promising,
> behavior. Randomly, I would get very quick responses. They were rare
> at first. /.../ This morning, all responses have been quick so far.
>
> So, the whole thing looks like a capacity issue to me. Not great if
> you are building a commercial app.

Sources:

- [Discusion 1](https://community.openai.com/t/gpt-3-5-api-is-very-slow-any-fix/141056)
- [Discusion 2](https://community.openai.com/t/openai-why-are-the-api-calls-so-slow-when-will-it-be-fixed/148339)